# Загрузка пикселей в массив

Tags: delphi, bmp

```
type
  TRGB = packed record
    B,G,R: byte;
  end;

...

ArRGBMap: array of array of TRGB;
```

Как через TOpenDialog загрузить цвета пикселей изображения bmp в массив `ArRGBMap` ?

Comment: Никак. TOpenDialog это диалог для выбора файла. Никакого отношения к извлечению пикселей он не имеет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  _pRGBTripple: PRGBTripple;
.....
bmp.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName); // Открыли картинку
bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;  // Установили формат в 24-бит
SetLength(ArGBMap, bmp.Height, bmp.Width); // Установили размер массива 
for J := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do // Цикл по строкам изображения
begin
  _pRGBTripple:= bmp.ScanLine[J]; // Получили указатель на пиксели текущей строки изображения
  Move(_pRGBTripple^, ArRGBMap[J], SizeOf(TRGBTripple) * bmp.Width); // Скопировали в массив
end;
```

Не забывайте подчищать за собой.